# using command line to extract large db file

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql

I have a large database file (1.5GB) named file.sql, I use "source" command to extract it into mysql databse but I receive lots of error messages. It used to work fine.

Here is a snapshot of part of the messages

```
Unknown command '\''.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\''.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\''.
ERROR:
Unknown command '\"'.
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '縺ｫ縺､縺・※</a></td>rn' (0)
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host '</tr>rn' (0)
```

When trying on a different computer, everything works fine.
Thank you for any concern.
No one helps ?

Comment: Maybe an encoding problem?

Answer (score 2):

Not much to go on here. Check that the input files are identical on both machines using something like md5sum

```
md5sum file.sql
76c004219056ff255686d3d73aba7e18  file.sql
```

They should both have the same checksum.